# AWS Elasticsearch VPC connectivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, networking, aws-elasticsearch

I've created an Elasticsearch domain in AWS.

It's added to my VPC inside a public subnet and I've attached a security group which is currently completely open.

I have this policy attached also:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:eu-central-1:ACCOUNT_ID:domain/DOMAIN_NAME/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to access an endpoint locally but it doesn't seem to be allowed.

The Kibana URL for example is:

https://vpc-bla.bla.bla.eu-central-1.es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/

Any idea why I'm not able to access this URL?

Comment: I'm stuck with the exact same problem. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: The URL generated by ES is internal and cannot be opened to the internet easily via security groups. Instead, I deployed an simple nginx proxy which forwarded public DNS requests eg `es.mydns.com` to the internal DNS eg `https://vpc-bla.bla.bla.eu-central-1.es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/`. More nginx info here https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try the same!

Comment: What if you add your desktop IP to the ES security group?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After much trial and error, I found the URL generated by ES is internal and cannot be opened to the internet easily via security groups.

Instead, I deployed an simple nginx proxy which forwarded public DNS requests eg `es.mydns.com` to the internal `DNS eg vpc....eu-central-1.es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/`

[More nginx info here.](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)

Comment: I did this, but then I get that "User anonmyous has no rights to access ["es:ESHttpGet"]...What is the correct way to create a policy for this to work? I created an EC2 full access role for the es domain but still it does not work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

VPC Endpoint cannot be accessed outside the subnets that you associated with the elastic-search domain.

you can try performing curl from any EC2 instances that is part of the same subnet that you associated with elastic-search, it should work.

If you need to access the endpoint from internet, then don't create VPC endpoint elastic-search instead create elastic-search domain with internet access. You can specify whether you want VPC or internet accessible cluster when creating the ES domain.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to access elastic search  VPC**

- Create ec2 environment in AWS.
- Install ngnix in ec2 and configure.
- Add two inbound request in    security group i.e.  all traffic and
  ssh.
- Then use public ip to    access from internet.

Comment: the answer will more eye catchy, if listed point wise.